# How to validate image size in each upload

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to upload the images which is greater than 900 pixels. so i do validate when upload. I have the plus sign when we click this another file button will appear.

The first input box values only i got. I couldn't get another files.

```
 <input type="file" id="upload_profile" class="upload_profile" name="upload_profile[]" />
```

Script:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$(".upload_profile").change(function(e) {
var file, img;
if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
});
```

Comment: Use `$(document).on('change', '.upload_profile', function (e) { ... });`

Comment: in your code variable i is not defined(var file, img, i=0;), and if i declared it then your given code is working fine. please use fiddler to know more http://fiddle.jshell.net/nzyu0q0q/

Comment: @Phylogenesis : Its working..Thank you

Comment: @SanjayBhardwaj : Yes I have noticed..thanks

Comment: Glad, you got your answer, your code was fine. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As other elements are not there in `DOM` when event is attached, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$(document).on('change', '.upload_profile', function () {
if (this.value) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function () {
        alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="upload_profile" name="upload_profile[]" /><br><br>
<input type="file" class="upload_profile" name="upload_profile[]" /><br><br>
<input type="file" class="upload_profile" name="upload_profile[]" /><br><br>
```